# Django: ValidationError message not showing in admin changeform

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on a webapp where user can be a member of one (and only one) organisation - this is done with a foreignkey in the `Profile` model, which in turn has a one-to-one link with the default `django.auth.user` model. We also want to make sure that each email address is only used once within each organisation. To do this we added the following function to the `Profile` model:

```
    def clean(self):
      if self.organisation and Profile.objects.filter(
            user__email=self.user.email,
            organisation_id=self.organisation.id
            ).exists():
        raise ValidationError({'user': _('The email address from this user is already used within this organisation!')})
      return super(Profile, self).clean()
```

However, when I add a user through the Django `admin` using an duplicate email address all that gets displayed is a generic `please fix the errors below` message at the top of the form. No text is displayed near the email field and the `ValidationError` text isn't displayed at all - thus giving the admins no information on what actually went wrong.

Does anyone know why the `ValidationError` message isnt being displayed in the admin, and what steps we can take to rectify this?

---

We are using a standard `ModelAdmin` class

```
class ProfileAdmin(ModelAdmin):

  def username(self, profile, **kwargs):
      return u'{} ({})'.format(
          profile.user.profile.full_name(),
          profile.user.username)

  search_fields = ['user__username', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name', 'user__email']
  list_display = ('username', 'organisation')
  list_filter = ('organisation')
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed minimal models and model admin classes to reproduce the problem. A screenshot might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've added the ModelAdmin that we are using. The model itself has a OneToOneField to the user (where it gets the email), some standard charfields for profile info and the Clean Method as shown in the example above

Comment: You’ve only added one of the three things I suggested. Your code looks ok to me, I can’t spot the problem. People are less likely to try out your code if they have to construct the models from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think form validation is a good idea in these type of situations.

**forms.py**

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        super(YourForm, self).clean()
        data1 = self.cleaned_data.get('data1')
        data2 = self.cleaned_data.get('data2')

        # Add validation condition here
        # if validation error happened you can raise the error 
        # and attach the error message with the field you want.

        self.add_error('field_name', 'error message')
```

In **admin.py**

```
class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = YourForm
```

Answer (score 1):

Raise `ValidationError` from **ProfileAdmin** class. For example, from `clean_<field name>` method.